# Deleting from std::list in a nested loop returns access violation

Tags: c++, access-violation, stdlist

I have a large list of elements, with possible duplicates. I want to delete those duplicates, but my program results in an access violation error after deleting around 700 items.

Here is my code:

```
for (auto it : endlist){        
    bool first = true;
    for (auto it2 : endlist){   
        if (!first){
            if (similar(it, it2)){
                endlist.remove(it2);
                continue;
            }
            rotate( it);

            if (similar(it, it2)){
                endlist.remove(it2);
                continue;
            }
            rotate(it);
            if (similar(it, it2)){
                endlist.remove(it2);
                continue;
            }
            rotate(it);
            if (similar(it, it2)){
                endlist.remove(it2);
                continue;
            }
        }
        first = false;
    }
}
```

The access violation is thrown in the second for loop. Can somebody explain why this happens?

Comment: By deleting elements of your list you'll change its size, gotta be careful how you iterate over it.

Comment: hmm. makes sense. do\ does memory addresses change on the fly when the list shrinks? does the compiler pull the rug from under me just like that?

Comment: I don't think so, but that shouldn't be your concern. The problem is that your for loops will iterate over the original size of the container.

Comment: If after one of the rotations it happens that `it1 == it2`, your program will delete `it1`, and then this is undefined behaviour. Besides, your algorithm is O(n^3).

Comment: i know my runtime is.... subpar. as for the undefined behaviour... hmm i see.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use

```
std::list::sort()
```

then

```
std::list::unique()
```

instead? It will get rid of all duplicates in a sorted list.

Comment: i didn't know these were a thing. my my... that helps a lot.
the problem is that i still need to ratate things to see if they're each others rotation or mirror. but this will help a lot

Comment: I don't know if op is actually using a std::list, but could definitely use `std::sort(endlist.begin(), endlist.end())`

Comment: i just ran the unique() code. The thing is i can't really sort these. It's a lix of matrixes, can only be compared to each other, if i iterate through element by element. Dispite that, unique culled it down from 15744 to 10692 elements. Unfortunatelly still access violation

Comment: Thank you Klaus for your response, but the problem is that the elements of the list are matrixes, that i don't really know how to compare to each other, therefore std::sort is not something that can be used here easily.

Comment: @Radnom_guy You can use your own comparison function std::list::sort(CompareFunc) where CompareFunc is a "less than" comparison function between two elements (matrices) in the list that returns a bool.

Answer (score 0):

**What you asked for:**

```
for (size_t i=0; i!=endlist.size(); ++i)
{
    for (size_t j=i+1; j!=endlist.size(); ++j)// only compare matrices once by using j=i+1
    {
        if (sometest(endlist[i],endlist[j]))
        {
            endlist.erase(endlist.begin()+j);  //  Also resizes the vector.
        }
    }
}
```

**What you didn't ask:**

If you have the ability to change your vector and elements according to your rotation this can be done cleaner with sorting.

For that you'll have to define an `operator<(...)` for your matrices, this should be possible by comparing their sizes and then comparing them lexicographically. Then you'll want to store the minimal matrix in terms of rotation in your endlist for this to make sense. Once that's done you can use the other answers approach for filtering.

And if you don't want to do anything with the duplicates anyway I'd recommend a container that doesn't allow duplicates from the beginning like a `std::map`.